# Efficiently Loading Multiple Keras Models in a python Dictionary

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have around 120 models trained and stored in multiple folders. I am trying to load these models into a dictionary for making predictions specific to their use cases.

But the problem is that since the dictionary is becoming too large, It is taking time to load these models as well as predict outputs.

Is there a more efficient way to load these models rather than in a python dictionary? I even tried loading these 120 models into 12 different dictionaries but it still is taking a hell lot of time to load and predict.

But the problem is that since the dictionary is becoming too large, It is taking time to load these models as well as predict outputs.

```py
model = {}
for _ in tqdm(os.listdir("wts_deep")):
    try:
        int(_[0])
        list_of_models = os.listdir("wts_deep/"+_)
        a = np.array([float(___.split("-")[3].split(".hdf5")[0]) for ___ in list_of_models])
        __ = np.where(a == a.max())[-1][-1]
        model[_] = load_model("wts_deep/"+str(_)+"/"+str(list_of_models[__]))
    except:
        print(_)
```

The loading of the models itself is taking around 33 mins

Comment: it doesn't matter how you store the model. Loading 120 deep learning models into memory will ofc take a lot of time. A similar case I have done is to load a big model that convert input to hidden state (embedding) before the output layer. And for each use case I would only need to load the output layer which takes those embedding to output.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest saving only models weights, re-construct the model architecture and load weights.
I also think that the slowness is not due to the dictionary usage. I think it is relating to Keras and/or the backend running your models.
If you are using Tensorflow, you may run into some issues if you try to load your models with the same session and graph.